# File exists but node says it doesn't

Tags: node.js, fs

***Update***
So, I went to test permissions using `fs.access`, and everything just started working again. Same console, just a new node repl session.
Not sure why it's working now, but I wish I could have made this post more useful. If I figure out why it happened I'll update this

So, very simply, I am trying to read a file from an absolute path using `fs.readFileSync`, and even though I can verify the file does in fact exist using my command line, `fs.readFileSync` throws an error and `fs.existsSync` returns false.

I'm on windows 8.1 running node v14.8.0.

Line of code in question (snipped for brevity):

```
//this line is in a constructor, fs, this.filepath, and this.config.fileFormat are all checked and valid
if(!initialContent) initialContent = fs.readFileSync(this.filepath,this.config.fileFormat)
```

Error produced:

```
Uncaught:
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\ShadowBan\Projects\SS\static\list.txt'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:465:3)
    at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:368:35)
    at new ListLoader (C:\Users\ShadowBan\Projects\SS\lib\loader.js:57:4
2) {
  errno: -4058,
  syscall: 'open',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  path: 'C:\\Users\\ShadowBan\\Projects\\SS\\static\\list.txt'
}
```

Output of dir on my console:

```
C:\Users\ShadowBan\Projects\SS>dir static
 Volume in drive C is OS
 Volume Serial Number is AB75-DE42

 Directory of C:\Users\ShadowBan\Projects\SS\static

03/17/2021  02:53 AM    <DIR>          .
03/17/2021  02:53 AM    <DIR>          ..
03/13/2021  07:34 PM             6,505 list.txt
               2 File(s)          8,477 bytes
               2 Dir(s)   3,540,754,432 bytes free
```

Comment: Node.js process might not have File System permissions to read that folder and file.